# React-Native navigation : Share data between components, update params when the state changes

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation, geolocation

I'm learning React-native and I'm blocking on navigation. before, when I updated a parent (his state), props and children were updating. So it was enough for me to provide the children with the methods to change the state of a parent.
But with the navigation, I don't know how to do it. 
The first "page" in the navigation gets the geolocation, which changes all the time, in his state, I want to give this data to the other components which succeed.

This method: `this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })` is not good for me because it's not dynamic. When the position changes, the other components which succeed don't change. And I want to be able to modify the state of a previous component in the navigation too.

Can you help me?

Comment: For that, I think you'll have to use Redux

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you're right. Ok, let's go!

Comment: Thanks it's perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

For that, I think you'll have to use Redux